# how remove git pack keep file by use git command

Tags: git

while push some code to a git server(github,gitcafe...), for some reason it failed/aborted, and left the .keep file  in `objects/pack`folder in server.

I want remove this file at local, is there any git command can remove this file?

Comment: What makes you think that the failure is anything to do with the `.keep` file?